# Understanding unit vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, vectors, coulombs-law

Trying to understand how the unit vector ${\mathcal{\hat{r}}}$ defined as $\frac{r' - r}{|r' - r|} $ (where $r'$ is the source point) works in this problem:

Work out the electric field, $E$, at point $P$ at height $z$ above a line of length $2L$ and charge $\lambda$ along the x-axis in the $x$-$z$ plane.

So I work it out to be: $$
\frac{2}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_0^{L} \frac{\lambda dx}{\mathcal{|r' - r|^2}} \hat{r} 
$$

But the books tells me that there it is actually:$$
\frac{2}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_0^{L} \frac{\lambda dx}{\mathcal{|r' - r|^2}} cos(\theta) \hat{z} 
$$

how is $\hat{r} =  \cos(\theta) \hat{z}$?
Can someone explain how the unit $z$ vector got in there?

Comment: Are you computing the electric field only along the z axis i.e (0,0,z)? Is the charged line positioned along x axis? That is what the solution you posted implies

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.

Comment: The x-components will cancel, so only the z component remains: this is where the $cos\theta$ comes from: $\vec{E}=E\sin\theta \hat{x} +E\cos\theta\hat{z}$